# Is this obfuscation?

Tags: ida

I'm trying to reverse a binary with IDA and it seems to be obfuscated, I have a variable: "EnableTeleportEffect" that I want to modify the values of later.

When jumping from the strings window, this is what I get:

```
.rdata:00007FF7C386F488 aEnableteleport:                        ; DATA XREF: sub_7FF7C1766A90+1533↑o
.rdata:00007FF7C386F488                 text "UTF-16LE", 'EnableTeleportEffect',0
.rdata:00007FF7C386F4B2                 align 8
```

When I jump to the xref, this is what I get:

```
.text:00007FF7C1767F97 loc_7FF7C1767F97:                       ; CODE XREF: sub_7FF7C1766A90+952↑j
.text:00007FF7C1767F97                 lea     rcx, dword_7FF7C4378B40
.text:00007FF7C1767F9E                 call    _Init_thread_header
.text:00007FF7C1767FA3                 cmp     cs:dword_7FF7C4378B40, 0FFFFFFFFh
.text:00007FF7C1767FAA                 jnz     loc_7FF7C17673E8
.text:00007FF7C1767FB0                 call    sub_7FF7C17D2AB0
.text:00007FF7C1767FB5                 mov     rbx, rax
.text:00007FF7C1767FB8                 call    sub_7FF7C17D2AB0
.text:00007FF7C1767FBD                 mov     r8d, 1
.text:00007FF7C1767FC3                 lea     rdx, aEnableteleport ; "EnableTeleportEffect"
.text:00007FF7C1767FCA                 lea     rcx, [rbp+arg_10]
.text:00007FF7C1767FCE                 call    sub_7FF7C1AE2B90
.text:00007FF7C1767FD3                 mov     rcx, rbx
.text:00007FF7C1767FD6                 mov     rdx, [rax]
.text:00007FF7C1767FD9                 call    sub_7FF7C152C1F0
.text:00007FF7C1767FDE                 lea     rcx, dword_7FF7C4378B40
.text:00007FF7C1767FE5                 mov     cs:qword_7FF7C4378B38, rax
.text:00007FF7C1767FEC                 call    _Init_thread_footer
.text:00007FF7C1767FF1                 jmp     loc_7FF7C17673E8
```

And when I jump to that xref, i get this:

```
.text:00007FF7C17673D9 loc_7FF7C17673D9:                       ; CODE XREF: sub_7FF7C1766A90+8A6↑j
.text:00007FF7C17673D9                 mov     eax, [r14]
.text:00007FF7C17673DC                 cmp     cs:dword_7FF7C4378B40, eax
.text:00007FF7C17673E2                 jg      loc_7FF7C1767F97
.text:00007FF7C17673E8
```

And it keeps going for quite a bit.

This is code obfuscation right?

Answer (score 2):

At first glance it does not look like code obfuscation, just like normal complexity. From the snippet I cannot tell you where the actual value is that you want to modify. Maybe the string is a key in a map, maybe it is just used for parsing and/or printing.